# How to compare HttpCheck and String types in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have problem with compare to types. I try to get some parameter from json and then compare it with String value. It looks like:

```
val x: HttpCheck = jsonPath("some path").saveAs("x")
```

and then

```
.exec(some code).asLongAs(x != "aaa") {
    some code
}
```

In this way it doesn't work. In know that I trided to comapre two diffrent types and I don't know how to convert HttpCheck to String. Do have any idea how to resolve this problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have an `x` value. All you have is `session` that stored something under `"x"` key. To retrive it from session you eithrer can do it explicitly

```
session.get("x").as[String]
```

or try to use [Gatling EL](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/expression_el/) `"${x}"`.  This *might* work:

```
.exec(some code).asLongAs("${x}" != "aaa") {
    some code
}
```